# Tween.js not callling call function after adding EventListener

Tags: javascript, html, tween

I am using tween.0.6.2 and ran into a problem.

Follwing code snippet (taken from [the tween.js Getting Started site](http://www.createjs.com/getting-started/tweenjs)  and slightly simplified) works just like it should:

```
            createjs.Tween.get(circle)
                .to({x: 400}, 1000, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(4))
                .call(function() {console.log("tween finished");});
```

After the tween has been finished (the circle has been moved to x=400) the function passed to `call` is executed.

But after an event handler was added like so:

```
            createjs.Tween.get(circle)
                .to({x: 400}, 1000, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(4))
                .addEventListener("change", function() {console.log("tween changed");} )
                .call(function() {console.log("tween finished");});
```

the function passed to `call` is not executed anymore.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

For everyone stumbling over this: after some experimenting, I found out that this works:

```
           createjs.Tween.get(circle)
                .to({x: 400}, 1000, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(4))
                .call(function() {console.log("tween finished");})
                .addEventListener("change", function() {console.log("tween changed");} )
```

As it seems, the call to `call` must precede the call to `addEventListener`.

EDIT:

Still not working the way it is expected to: in the above example, the event listener gets called one more time after(!) the function passed to `call` is executed.

Ideas as to why this is happening are still welcome ...

Answer (score -1):

`addEventListener` is not tween-js function. All chained functions like `to` and `call` assuming to return `this` object (instance of Tween) and `addEventListener` returns `undefined`. So, last `call()` will called upon `undefined`.

You must use `onUpdate` instead of `addEventListener`:

```
         createjs.Tween.get(circle)
                .to({x: 400}, 1000, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(4))
                .onUpdate(function() {console.log("tween changed");} )
                .call(function() {console.log("tween finished");});
```

Comment: I suppose the tween.js API has undergone some major changes lately. As of tween.0.6.2 there is no onUpdate function anymore (see http://www.createjs.com/docs/tweenjs/classes/Tween.html). Also addEventListener did not return undefined in my first example.

Comment: Yep, my fault. Im using another version of tween.